# Python-Recursion-New To Programming

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.3

I need to Check that every number in `numberList` is positive and implement the below 
function using recursion. I'm stuck. Just learning recursion and I'm completely lost as I am very new to programming. Help!

```
def isEveryNumberPositiveIn(numberList):
        foundCounterexampleYet = False

        for number in numberList:
            if(number <= 0):
                foundCounterexampleYet = True
                return not(foundCounterexampleYet)
```

Comment: The indentation of `if(number <= 0):` appears to be incorrect, but I assume that it is part of the previous function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect, but your thinking is correct, though the algorithm is not recursive. You could make it a bit more efficient though, by jumping out of the loop when a negative number is detected:

```
def isEveryNumberPositiveIn(numberList):
    foundCounterexampleYet = False
    for number in numberList:
        if number <= 0:
            foundCounterexampleYet = True
            break
    return not foundCounterexampleYet
```

then for example:

```
a = [1,-2,3,4,45]
print(isEveryNumberPositiveIn(a))
```

returns `False`

By the way, those parentheses for`if` and `not` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your function is not recursive because it never calls itself; a recursive version would look like

   ```
   def all_positive(lst):
       if lst:
           return lst[0] > 0 and all_positive(lst[1:])
           #                       ^
           #             this is the recursive bit -
           #             the function calls itself
       else:
           return True
           #      this keeps the function from looping forever -
           #      when it runs out of list items, it stops calling itself
   ```
2. This is a bad example to choose for a recursive function because (a) there is a simple non-recursive solution and (b) passing it a large list (ie over 1000 items) will overflow the call stack and crash your program. Instead, try:

   ```
   def all_positive(lst):
       return all(i > 0 for i in lst)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With this sort of recursive problem, here is how you should think about it:

- There should be a "basis case", which answers the question trivially.
- There should be a part that does something that brings you closer to a solution.

In this case, the "basis case" will be an empty list.  If the list is empty, then return `True`.

The part that brings you closer to a solution: shorten the list.  Once the list get shortened all the way to a zero-length (empty) list, you have reached the basis case.

In pseudocode:

```
define function all_positive(lst)
    # basis case
    if lst is zero-length:
        return True

    if the first item in the list is not positive:
        return False

    # the actual recursive call
    return all_positive(lst[with_first_value_removed]
```

Try to convert the above pseudocode into Python code and get it working.  When you are ready to peek at my answer, it's below.

```
def all_positive(lst):
    """
    Recursive function to find out if all members of lst are positive.

    Because it is recursive, it must only be used with short lists.
    """
    # basis case
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True

    if lst[0] <= 0:
        return False

    # recursive call
    return all_positive(lst[1:])
```

There's several ways you can write this.  One way would be to use `lst.pop()` to remove one element from the list.  You could combine that with the `if` statement and it would be kind of elegant.  Then the list would already be shortened and you could just do the recursive call with the list.

```
    if lst.pop() <= 0:
        return False

    return all_positive(lst)
```

There is one problem though: this destroys the list!  Unless the caller knows that it destroys the list, and the caller makes a copy of the list, this is destructive.  It's just plain dangerous.  It's safer to do it the way I wrote it above, where you use "list slicing" to make a copy of the list that leaves off the first item.

Usually in a language like Python, we want the safer program, so we make copies of things rather than destructively changing them ("mutating" them, as we say).

Here's one more version of `all_positive()` that makes a single copy of the list and then destroys that copy as it works.  It relies on a helper function; the helper is destructive.  We don't expect the user to call the helper function directly so it has a name that starts with an underscore.

```
def _all_positive_helper(lst):
    """
    Recursive function that returns True if all values in a list are positive.

    Don't call this directly as it destroys its argument; call all_positive() instead.
    """
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True

    if lst.pop() <= 0:
        return False

    return _all_positive_helper(lst)

def all_positive(lst):
    """
    Return True if all members of lst are positive; False otherwise.
    """
    # use "list slicing" to make a copy of the list
    lst_copy = lst[:]

    # the copy will be destroyed by the helper but we don't care!
    return _all_positive_helper(lst_copy)
```

It's actually possible in Python to use a default argument to implement the above all in one function.

```
def all_positive(lst, _lst_copy=None):
    """
    Return True if all members of lst are positive; False otherwise.
    """
    if _lst_copy is None:
        return all_positive(lst, lst[:])

    if len(_lst_copy) == 0:
        return True

    if _lst_copy.pop() <= 0:
        return False

    return all_positive(lst, _lst_copy)
```

Recursion doesn't really help you with this.  A better use for recursion would be, for example, visiting every node in a binary tree.